# python circular import error

Tags: python, python-2.7

There is following structure:

```
bin.py
package/
  __init__.py
  a.py
  b.py
```

Content of bin.py:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import package
```

Content of __init__.py:

```
import a
```

Content of a.py:

```
print "a >> begin"
print "a >> import b"
import b
print "a << import b"

def Print():
    print b.var

print "a << end"
```

Content of b.py:

```
print "  b >> begin"
print "  b >> import a"
import a
print "  b << import a"

var = 3
a.Print()

print "  b << end"
```

If I run python './package/a.py' - all is ok.

```
./package/a.py
a >> begin
a >> import b
  b >> begin
  b >> import a
a >> begin
a >> import b
a << import b
a << end
  b << import a
3
  b << end
a << import b
a << end
```

If I run python './bin.py', I catch error.

```
./bin.py
a >> begin
a >> import b
  b >> begin
  b >> import a
  b << import a
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./bin.py", line 2, in <module>
    import package
  File "/home/fervid/Projects/AutoClassification-Python/package/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    import a
  File "/home/fervid/Projects/AutoClassification-Python/package/a.py", line 3, in <module>
    import b
  File "/home/fervid/Projects/AutoClassification-Python/package/b.py", line 7, in <module>
    a.Print()
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Print'
```

What is the difference?

Comment: What about running `python './package/b.py'`?

Answer (score 1):

When you run/`import` `a.py` before `b.py`:

```
a >> begin
a >> import b
  b >> begin
  b >> import a
a >> begin
a >> import b
a << import b  # see here? 
a << end
  b << import a
3
  b << end
a << import b
a << end
```

The second call to `import b` finds that there is **already a `b` loaded** (although at that point it's only part-way through), so returns to `a` to finish that `import`. Therefore when it returns to finish loading `b`, `a.Print` has been defined.

---

However, when you run/`import` `b.py` before `a.py`:

```
  b >> begin
  b >> import a
a >> begin
a >> import b
  b >> begin
  b >> import a
  b << import a  # oh dear

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\so\package\b.py", line 3, in <module>
    import a
  File "C:\Python27\so\package\a.py", line 3, in <module>
    import b
  File "C:\Python27\so\package\b.py", line 7, in <module>
    a.Print()
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Print'
```

`a` has started importing when `import b` starts, but `a.Print` hasn't been defined yet (we haven't reached `a << import b`, let alone `a << end`). However, as `b` hasn't previously started importing, it tries to load all of `b` before `a` has finished.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for your issue is as described by jonrsharpe.

To fix the issue, you need to make sure you import b.py before importing a.py in `__init__.py` .

The contents of `__init__.py` would become -

```
import b
import a
```

Comment: Actually, to fix the issue the OP shouldn't make `b.py` rely on functions from the file that imports it!

Comment: I understand that having cyclic dependency is very bad, but there may be cases that it is unavoidable, I am guessing the above is just a minimalistic example to to reproduce the OP's issue, but if it is really important that he keeps the structure as is, and fix the issue, I would say importing b before a should do it.